# What do you call a facility that accepts recyclables?

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrases

What do you call a facility that accepts recyclables? Not just the blue bins that you have in America but something like this:

[image: building with bins for each type of recyclable]

They don't actually recycle there, just collect and then sell to large warehouses (and then it's shipped to recycling plants). What you see is an environmental nonprofit, but it could be a private business too (in the latter case, they may have their own warehouses and ship recyclables directly to recyclers).

Comment: It's not clear from the picture whether that is a transfer station or whether recycling is actually done there. In the New York area several terms might be used, including "recycling center", "recycling depot", and "waste sorting facility".

Comment: @MarcInManhattan no, they don't actually recycle there, just collect and then sell to large warehouses (and then it's shipped to recycling plants). What you see is an environmental nonprofit, but it could be a private business too (in the latter case, they may have their own warehouses and ship recyclables directly to recyclers)

Comment: The technical term is [Materials recovery facility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materials_recovery_facility) (materials reclamation facility, materials recycling facility) but both sorting and  recycling can be done there. Perhaps, you could use "recycling sorting center/facility" to emphasize that it is only used for sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a **recycling processing facility**. According to the EPA page [The U.S. Recycling System](https://www.epa.gov/recyclingstrategy/us-recycling-system):

> The materials are transported by the collector to a processing facility, such as a materials recovery facility or paper processor. At the processing facility, the recyclables are sorted, cleaned of contaminants and prepared for transport to a milling facility or directly to a manufacturing facility. Some commodities may require additional processing for additional sorting and decontamination. For example, glass and plastic are often sent to glass beneficiation plants and plastics reclaimers, respectively, where they are processed into mill-ready forms.

Instead of calling it a *facility*, it can also be called a *plant* or *center*.

Answer (score 1):

I would call them "recycling centers" or even a "recycling point", but in this case a large facility/center to hold these. ["**Recycling depot**"](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/recycling-depot) fits your description perfectly:

> Recycling Depot means a facility for the collection, repackaging and shipping of recyclable materials. Recyclable materials include paper, plastic, glass, tin or any other product that can be recycled